# Handling Event for multiple Sprite with one Event Listener in Andengine

Tags: andengine

In my app i need to add multiple sprite and add event to them. What i am doing now is using individual event listener for each and every sprite which is a kind of mess.

```
buttonS[0] = new Sprite(x_pos += 0, y_pos, orangeNumImage[0], this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                //Perform Some task
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                //Perform Some task
                return false;
            }
        }
    };


    buttonS[1] = new Sprite(x_pos += 115, y_pos, orangeNumImage[1], this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {               
                //Perform Some task
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
```

I was searching to handle this event with just one event listener and make the code shorter.

In normal android (without andengine) we could use something like this (by using android:onclick to areaTouched in button):-

```
public void areaTouched(View view) {
    Button nextclick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_nextClick);
    Button b = (Button)view;
    int check = Integer.parseInt(b.getText().toString());
    if (check == i){
          ........
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the `Sprite` class and add a method to add you own `TouchListener` and a method to set some user data. Or implement the touch logic in your new `Sprite` child class by overriding the `onAreaTouched` method. I don't think there is any other mechanism in AndEngine that would allow you to register a touch listener to Sprites.

Comment: This concurs with what I tried to describe in the AndEngine forum.